# fatal error: openjpeg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, debian, openjpeg

I'm trying to install OpenCV4 on Debian 10 server. I followed the official [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) , but compiling I get

```
In file included from /root/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.cpp:10:
/root/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_jpeg2000_openjpeg.hpp:13:10: fatal error: openjpeg.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openjpeg.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I installed `openjpeg` separately from source ([this](https://wiki.harvard.edu/confluence/display/DigitalImaging/Installing+OpenJPEG+on+Windows+10%2C+Linux%2C+and+MacOS) guide)

But it did not help.

I also tried to install opencv4 using `pip3 install opencv-python`  but again, I failed:

> An error occurred while building with CMake.
> Command:
> cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
> Install target:
> install
> Source directory:
> /tmp/pip-install-58cut84q/cmake
> Working directory:
> /tmp/pip-install-58cut84q/cmake/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build
> Please check the install target is valid and see CMake's output for more information.
>
> ```
>   ----------------------------------------   Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-58cut84q/cmake/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
> --record /tmp/pip-record-wvupk349/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-uyj03w3k --compile" failed with error code 1 in
> /tmp/pip-install-58cut84q/cmake/

So I'm left clueless and appreciate your help.

Comment: To check whether the file openjpeg.h actually exists can you run `sudo find / -name "openjpeg.h"`.

If the file is installed on your system the command should return the path to the file.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install libopenjp2-7-dev` to get the headers? Also you may need to pass correct include path to cmake when compiling from sources.